# How to ignore error message in R and keep loop function going

Tags: r

I'm using a loop function to get some `urls` inside a `df` and do some validation, like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
webpage <- read_html(as.character(df[i,1]))
Sys.sleep(0.025)
validation <- webpage %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr('href')
if (length(grep("bitstream",validation)>0)) {
  df$text[[i]] <- "Valid"}
else {
  df$text[[i]] <- "Invalid"}
}
```

The problem is that if and `url` is `broken` i get an error message like this:

`Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500`

and the loop stops.
Is there a way to set another `if condition` so it doesn't stop?

Comment: there are some answers on SO that identify how to deal with this but I'm a bit short on time to pull up search results. I usually do `srh <- purrr::safely(read_html)` and use `srh()` instead of `read_html()` and test the `$result` component of the return value. Alternately, wrap the `read_html()` call with `try()` or `tryCatch()` and test the result.

Comment: tryCatch worked for me, even though i had to use a different condition for it to work! But thanks anyway =)

Comment: you could post what worked as an answer which may, in turn, help future askers (and you'd get at _least_ one upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've used `tryCatch` as @hrbrmstr suggested in the comments, but added a little thing so it would work better.
Using an `valid_url` checking condition among an `next` statement for the loop to start over again.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

valid_url <- TRUE

tryCatch({webpage <- read_html(as.character(df[i,1]))}, error=function(e) url_valido<<-FALSE)

if (!valid_url){ cat("\014")  
cat(paste(i," - Invalid URL","\nStatus: ",
          percent(i/nrow(df)),sep=""))
df$text[[i]] <- "Invalid URL"

next}

Sys.sleep(0.025)
teste <- webpage %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr('href')
if (length(grep("bitstream",teste)>0)) {

  df$texto[[i]] <- "Completo"}
else {
  df$texto[[i]] <- "Incompleto"}
cat("\014")  
cat(paste(i," - ",df$texto[[i]],"\nStatus: ",
            percent(i/nrow(df)),sep=""))
}
```