# Rvest 'Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero' for specific websites -- why?

Tags: r, rvest

```
library(rvest)
url = 'vzbvastgoed.nl'
html_nodes(html_session(url), 'body')
```

This is my code. For different websites, it works, but it throws an error:

> Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero
> request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
> httr::GET(url, x$config, ..., handle = x$handle)
> request_GET(session, url)
> html_session(url)
> html_nodes(html_session(url), "body")

Searching online and on stackoverflow didn't really help :( seems to be a rather rare case or unknown.

Comment: Does it always throw an error? Or just with special urls? If I use the syntax with different urls, it seems to work without any error. But the one you provided returns Status 403 ^^

Comment: @sambold Just this website -- I'm assuming that there are certain websites that throw this error and I only found the first one. I tested the same code with several other URLs and they all seem to work fine. I'm not sure why it's not working on this one.

Also it's strange that you get 403 error. The website works for me.

However, I found another website that throws 404 error. Is it possible for the code to ignore the errors so that it continues a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate the problem:

```r
library(rvest)
url = 'vzbvastgoed.nl'
session <- html_session(url)
#> Error in if (is_http) {: Argument hat Länge 0
html_nodes(session, 'body')
#> Error in html_nodes(session, "body"): Objekt 'session' nicht gefunden
```

It seems that it does not properly resolve the url, so let us try:

```r
url = 'https://vzbvastgoed.nl'
session <- html_session(url)
#> Warning in request_GET(session, url): Forbidden (HTTP 403).
html_nodes(session, 'body')
#> Error in read_xml.response(x$response, ..., as_html = as_html): Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

At least we have a meanungful error now (HTTP 403).
My guess is this site wants to protext itself from harvesting and block requests
that do not come from a browser, because this worked for me:

```r
library(httr)
url = 'https://vzbvastgoed.nl'
session <- html_session(url, add_headers(`User-agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1"))
html_nodes(session, 'body')
#> {xml_nodeset (1)}
#> [1] <body>\r\n<div id="maindiv">\r\n\t<div id="kop">\r\n\t\t <div id="zoekfor ...
```

Of course, you have to ask yourself if you want to circumvent the site owner's regulations like that. But, technically, it works.

<sup>Created on 2020-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hmm I see! Thank you very much. Perfect clarification. 

Now my question is how to ignore those errors so that my for-loop can continue. Is there a way?

Comment: I marked the question as solved, but should I create a new post for ignoring the errors?

Comment: According to the philosophy of SO it would be best to create a new question. But you should look into a few posts, first, because the same question has been asked only with different context (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892518/ignore-error-when-importing-json-files-in-r) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194820/how-to-ignore-error-message-in-r-and-keep-loop-function-going)). Especially the second example may help you out.